# Simulate ajax response with jsfiddle and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsfiddle

Can I simulate an ajax response in jsfiddle?  http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html describes using `new Request.HTML`, however, it appears to only be available with Mootools, and I get an error when using it with jQuery (`ReferenceError: Request is not defined`).  For instance, in my below example, I would like to alert "returned data" upon clicking "start".

```
<button id="start">start</button>

/*
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: "returned data",
        delay: 3
    },
    method: 'get',
    update: 'target'
}).send();
*/

$('#start').click(function () {
    $.get("/echo/html/", function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naaarcnk/

Comment: Your code is working, you just didn't tell /echo/html to.. echo anything.

Comment: @KevinB  That's the question.  How do I tell `/echo/html` to echo something?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naaarcnk/1/ it has to be a post, and it has to have data such as in the mootools example.

Comment: Basically, just mimic exactly what the mootools code is doing, using jQuery syntax.

Comment: Perfect.  So you just send an object with the content with the request.  Thank you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @KevinB  Have never played with mootools, so didn't even at the time they were doing an ajax request.  Would have been nice if the jsfiddle docs had a jquery example.  Thanks again!

Comment: @FelixKling  I understood how to use jQuery's `get`, but didn't know one had to pass the desired response with it.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example jsfiddle gives uses mootools, however, you can do the same request with any language, you just have to mimic it's method and data.

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/', // the target url
    data: {  // the data to send (next 3 lines too)
        html: "returned data",
        delay: 3
    },
    method: 'get', // the method to use
    update: 'target' // target html element to update
}).send();
```

jQuery way:

```
$('target').load('/echo/html/', {html: 'returned data', delay: 3});
```

or

```
$.post('/echo/html', {html: 'returned data', delay: 3}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```